# Check boxes in jqgrid check after a dialog box closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have jqgrid that contain a check boxes( True or False ) 2 check boxes. And before I check those checkboxes I need to click a check box first to trigger the open dialog box that contains my jqgrid. However I got a problem for example I got a 3 data and I only check the row 2(true) and 3(false). After I close my dialog box all of the check boxes in row 2 and 3 becomes checked. What is the problem?.

Comment: Repost. I hope someone can read it again.